# Why is saving image as a jpeg file not changing the image when saving it n times

Tags: matlab

I'm using matlab 2015. I know that by saving a jpeg file n time data is lost, because jpeg compression is lossy, but nothing changes when running code below

Code:

```
N = 100;
imfinfo('temp.jpg')

for i = 1: N
    image = uint8(imread('temp.jpg'));
    imwrite(image, 'temp.jpg','jpeg', 'Quality', 90,'Mode','lossy');
    figure(0)
    imshow(image)
    imfinfo('temp.jpg')
end
```

Answer (score 2):

When you save a jpeg you get a certain loss of information. While being more complicated in real, imagine the last digits of a floating point being cut off to reduce the amount of information, thus the file size. When you read it again, it is already a image which contains less information which can be stored in a jpeg without further loss. To stick with the simplification, cutting off the last digits again won't cause further trouble because they are already zero.